# R ggplot2::geom_vline legend not displaying line type correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying this simple task in which I wish to add two vertical lines to a ggplot object, with different colours and different line types, and colours/lines correctly specified in a legend. I've been looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660694/add-legend-to-geom-vline) in which two `geom_vline`s are plotted. If you change one of their line types e.g. to solid, the legend wrongly displays the line types. It turns all lines to solids.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length), data = iris) + 
  geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = NA) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(iris$Sepal.Length),
                 color = "median"), 
             linetype = "solid", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length),
                 color = "mean"), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "statistics", 
    values = c(median = "blue", mean = "red"))
```

[image]

I also tried simply the following without any added data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot() + theme_bw() + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = c(0, 0.2), 
                 color = c("Zero", "Pooled")), 
             size = 1, linetype = c("solid", "dotdash")) +
scale_color_manual(
  name = "statistics", 
  values = c(Zero = "black", Pooled = "blue"))
```

in which the linetypes were wrongly displayed on the legend.

[image]

Can anyone pinpoint me to what's going on and how I can get the line types to display correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `linetype` in the `aes` call, the same way you did for colour:

```
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length), data = iris) + 
    geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = NA) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(iris$Sepal.Length),
                   color = "median", linetype = 'median'), 
               size = 1) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length),
                   color = "mean", linetype = "mean"), 
               size = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(
        name = "statistics", 
        values = c(median = "blue", mean = "red")) +
    scale_linetype_manual(
        name = "statistics", 
        values = c(median = "solid", mean = "dashed"))
```

Using named vectors when you're specifying which value matches up to which linetype also helps - I think the reason your second example fails is that in the legend, ggplot assigns the linetypes to the levels in alphabetical order.

Output:

[image]

Comment: You should also remove the instances of `iris$` inside `aes`.