# Wrong legend in ggplot output

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-vline

The output of this code gives a distribution and two vertical lines, one red and one blue. But in the legend the blue line is marked "red" and vice versa. What might be the reason? [Distribution and 2 vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZKpw.png)

```
variances <- apply(matrix(rexp(40*1000,0.2),1000),1,var) 
hist(variances)
v_theo <- 45 ## need to define v_theo
g <- ggplot(data.frame(x=variances), aes(x = x)) 
g <- g + geom_density(alpha=0.2,size=1,fill="red")
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(variances),color="red"), size=1) 
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = (v_theo),color="blue"), size=1) 
g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the colors are mapped by the `aes` function. If you want to map them manually, you could either take them out of the `aes` like this

```
variances <- apply(matrix(rexp(40*1000,0.2),1000),1,var) 
hist(variances)
g <- ggplot(data.frame(x=variances), aes(x = x)) 
g <- g + geom_density(alpha=0.2,size=1,fill="red")
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(variances)), color="red", size=1) 
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = (v_theo)), color="blue", size=1) 
g
```

You'll lose the legen by doing this though. If you want the legend, you can use `scale_color_manual` to fix the order of the colors.

```
variances <- apply(matrix(rexp(40*1000,0.2),1000),1,var) 
hist(variances)
g <- ggplot(data.frame(x=variances), aes(x = x)) 
g <- g + geom_density(alpha=0.2,size=1,fill="red")
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(variances),color="red"), size=1) 
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = (v_theo),color="blue"), size=1) 
g <- g + scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
variances <- apply(matrix(rexp(40*1000,0.2),1000),1,var) 
hist(variances)
v_theo <- 45


g <- ggplot(data.frame(x=variances), aes(x = x)) 
g <- g + geom_density(alpha=0.2,size=1,fill="red")
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = v_theo, color="blue"), size=1) 
g
```

[image]

```
g <- ggplot(data.frame(x=variances), aes(x = x)) 
g <- g + geom_density(alpha=0.2,size=1,fill="red")
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(variances),color="mean"), size=1) 
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = v_theo,color="v_theo"), size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend name", values = c(mean = "red", v_theo = "blue"))
g
```

[image]

See here as well:
[Add legend to geom_vline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660694/add-legend-to-geom-vline)